# MySQL time difference from a record with 3 fixed breaks excluded

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a database where I also need to find the time difference inside a record. However, **timediff()** does not give the result I need. What I mean is that
there are 3 fixed time intervals in every day and each record stores **time_1** & **time_2** datetime entries.

My question is, for example, if **time_1='2020-01-01 04:30'** and **time_2= '2020-01-08 15:45'** of a single record is given, then how is it possible to find exact time difference in that record?

For simplicity, we can assume that
**fixedtime1** is the interval **5:00 and 6:00**,
**fixedtime2** is the interval **13:00 and 14:00** and
**fixedtime3** is the interval **21:00 and 22:00**.
The point where I am stuck at is how to write the code for it. You can calculate it inside your head easily for the record obtained.

I want to add an table as an example, but I have the raw data and it contains **longtext** and date only. I am at the step of creating the database and tables. I want to plan it beforehand for the idea above.
I am trying to find out the the necessary code to find the **duration** from **fixedtime1**, **fixedtime2**, **fixedtime3** & **time_1**,**time_2**

From the example, **duration** = datediff(time_2,time_1)*21 + timediff(time_2,'2020-01-08 04:30')

```
create table TestTable(
id int primary key,
time_1 datetime not null,
time_2 datetime not null,
textbox text);
insert into testtable(id,time_1,time_2)
values
(1,'2020-01-01 4:30','2020-01-08 15:45'),
(2,'2021-05-06 16:55','2021-07-01 23:15'),
(3,'2021-12-30 19:55','2022-01-02 03:10');
```

[image: Visual Description]

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, and desired output for this data. Add detailed explanations for each output value. All possible combinations must present in source data.

Comment: What defines a "break"?

Comment: The break is for meal breaks i.e breakfast, lunch and dinner times. It s meant to calculate time difference for a record while excluding "break" if the time period intersects

Answer (score 0):

I found the way out (it's my own work) but it's quite long for just a single calculation. If anyone can simplify it, it would be a good deed.

```
drop table if exists testtable;
create table TestTable(
id int primary key,
time_1 datetime not null,
time_2 datetime not null,
textbox text);
insert into testtable(id,time_1,time_2)
values
(1,'2020-01-01 4:30','2020-01-08 15:45'),
(2,'2021-05-06 16:55','2021-07-01 23:15'),
(3,'2021-12-30 19:55','2022-01-02 03:10'),
(4,'2021-12-31 23:59','2022-01-01 05:14'),
(5,'2022-01-01 01:01','2021-01-01 21:30');

select  
case    
when    time(time_2)>=time(time_1)
then
    case
    when (time(time_1)>"00:00:00"   and time(time_1)<='03:45:00') and (time(time_2)>"19:00:00"  and time(time_2)<='23:59:59')       /*subcase1 when stoptime is btw 0-3:45 & starttimme btw 19-24  */
    then    
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 -   180
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 -   180
        end
    
    when    (time(time_1)>"00:00:00"    and time(time_1)<='03:45:00') and (time(time_2)>"13:00:00"  and time(time_2)<='17:59:59')   /*subcase1.1 when stoptime is btw 0-3:45 & starttimme btw 13-18  */
    then
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 - 120
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 - 120

        end

    WHEN    (time(time_1)>"00:00:00"    and time(time_1)<='03:45:00') or (time(time_2)>"04:44:59"   and time(time_2)<='11:59:59')   /*subcase1.1.1 when stoptime is btw 0-3:45 & starttimme btw 4:45-12  */
    then    
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 - 60
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 - 60
        end
            
    WHEN    (time(time_1)>"04:44:59"    and time(time_1)<='11:59:59') or (time(time_2)>"12:59:59"   and time(time_2)<='17:59:59')   /*subcase1.1.2 when stoptime is btw 4:45-12 & starttimme btw 13-18  */
    THEN    
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 - 60
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 - 60
        end
    when    (time(time_1)>"04:44:59"    and time(time_1)<='12:00:00') and (time(time_2)>"19:00:00"  and time(time_2)<='23:59:59')   /*subcase1.1 when stoptime is btw 4:45-12 & starttimme btw 19-24  */
    then
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 - 120
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 - 120
        end
    WHEN    (time(time_1)>"04:44:59"    and time(time_1)<='11:59:59') or (time(time_2)>"12:59:59"   and time(time_2)<='17:59:59')   /*subcase1.2.1 when stoptime is btw 13-18 & starttimme btw 18-24  */
    THEN    
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 -   60
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 -   60
        end
    WHEN    (time(time_1)>"12:59:59"    and time(time_1)<='17:59:59') or (time(time_2)>"18:59:59"   and time(time_2)<='23:59:59')   /*subcase1.2.2 when stoptime is btw 13-18 & starttimme btw 18-24  */
    THEN    
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 -   60
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60 -   60
        end
    ELSE        /*subcase1.3 when stoptime & starttime are out of bounds*/
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(time(time_2),time(time_1)))/60
        end

    END
    


ELSE 
    
CASE WHEN time(time_1)>time(time_2) 
    THEN
    case
    when (time(time_2)>"00:00:00"   and time(time_2)<='03:45:00') and (time(time_1)>"19:00:00"  and time(time_1)<='23:59:59')       /*subcase2 when starttime is btw 0-3:45 & sttimme btw 19-24  */
    then    
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    (time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))-1)*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 180
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 180
        end
    
    when    (time(time_2)>"00:00:00"    and time(time_2)<='03:45:00') and (time(time_1)>"13:00:00"  and time(time_1)<='17:59:59')   /*subcase2.1 when starttime is btw 0-3:45 & stoptimme btw 13-18  */
    then
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    (time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))-1)*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 120
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 120
        end

    WHEN    (time(time_2)>"00:00:00"    and time(time_2)<='03:45:00') or (time(time_1)>"04:44:59"   and time(time_1)<='11:59:59')   /*subcase2.1.1 when starttime is btw 0-3:45 & stoptimme btw 4:45-12  */
    then    
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    (time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))-1)*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 60
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 60
        end
            
    WHEN    (time(time_2)>"04:44:59"    and time(time_2)<='11:59:59') or (time(time_1)>"12:59:59"   and time(time_2)<='17:59:59')   /*subcase2.1.2 when starttime is btw 4:45-12 & stoptimme btw 13-18  */
    THEN    
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    (time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))-1)*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 60
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 60
        end
    when    (time(time_2)>"04:44:59"    and time(time_2)<='12:00:00') and (time(time_1)>"19:00:00"  and time(time_1)<='23:59:59')   /*subcase2.2 when starttime is btw 4:45-12 & stoptimme btw 19-24  */
    then
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    (time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))-1)*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 120
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 120
        end
    WHEN    (time(time_2)>"04:44:59"    and time(time_2)<='11:59:59') or (time(time_1)>"12:59:59"   and time(time_1)<='17:59:59')   /*subcase2.2.1 when stoptime is btw 13-18 & starttimme btw 18-24  */
    THEN    
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    (time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))-1)*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 60
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 60
        end
    WHEN    (time(time_1)>"12:59:59"    and time(time_1)<='17:59:59') or (time(time_2)>"18:59:59"   and time(time_2)<='23:59:59')   /*subcase2.2.2 when stoptime is btw 13-18 & starttimme btw 18-24  */
    THEN    
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    (time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))-1)*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 60
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 60
        end
    ELSE        /*subcase2.3 when stoptime & starttime are out of bounds*/
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    (time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))-1)*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 60
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 60
        end

    END
        ELSE        /*subcase2.3 when stoptime & starttime are out of bounds*/
        case    
        when    datediff(time_2,time_1)>=1 
        then    (time_to_sec(datediff(time_2,time_1))-1)*21*60 + 
                TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 60
        else    TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('24:00:00',timediff(time(time_1),time(time_2))))/60    - 60
        end

    end

end as gg

from testtable
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).